# Pass js variable to modal in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have a
- button that opens a modal window, and
- jquery dynatree.

How can I pass variable from js (the id of the selected node in the tree) to modal in Yii?

```
//the modal window
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
'id' => 'createExercise',
'header' => 'Create..',
'content' => $this->renderPartial('_form', ['model'=>$model], 1),
'footer' => [
    TbHtml::button('Save', ['onclick'=>'$("#exercise-form").submit()']),
 ],
));

//the button
TbHtml::button('Create', array(
'id' => '#btnCreate',
'data-toggle' => 'modal',
'data-target' => '#createExercise',
));
```

I get the ID of active node from tree with this code:
`$("#yw0").dynatree("getActiveNode").data.id;`

How can be passed this ID to the modal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it from your button, using the `onClick` Attribute 
modify the button to this

```
TbHtml::button('Create', array(
'id' => '#btnCreate',
'data-toggle' => 'modal',
'data-target' => '#createExercise',
'onClick'=>'js:PassToModal($("#yw0").dynatree("getActiveNode").data.id)',
));
```

In you js function you can do what you want with value, for example you want to populate the modal with some dynamic data depending on node value you can do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PassToModal(id){
        <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=>$this->createurl('getDetails'),
            'type'=>'GET',
            'dataType'=>'html',
            'data'=>array('id'=>'js:id'),
            'update'=>'#createExerciseBody'// Id of the Modal Body
        )); ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: In Yii2, instead of `js:PassToModal...` you can use `new \yii\web\JsExpression("PassToModal...")`